# Dynamically set image resource to a list-item

Tags: android

I'm creating a custom `ListView` with multiple elements - `TextView` and `ImageView`.

Here's a part of my `getView` method:

```
@override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.individual_items_in_options, parent, false);
        }

        // Find the option to start with.
        Options currentOption = optionsOfAQuestion.get(position);

        // option number
        TextView optionNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.option_number);
        optionNumber.setText(currentOption.getOptionNumber());

        // option content
        TextView optionContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.option_content);
        optionContent.setText(currentOption.getOptionContent());

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.option_icon);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_wrong);
```

I'm getting NPE while setting the image resource, though I've defined it in my layout. Why is setting image giving me NPE, while setting the TextViews work completely fine? What's the point I'm missing here?

Comment: You missed `itemView` for calling `findViewById`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.option_icon);
```

by this

```
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option_icon);
```

this will help you

Comment: mistypes. Sorry, I completely missed this. Thanks for the response.

Comment: no problem ! if it fixed your issue don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Please Update your code like below

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView .findViewById(R.id.option_icon);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_wrong);
```